# Graphql Conditional variables in Queries

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, postgraphile

I would like to have the variables I do not use be completely omitted to avoid errors like `"Variable "$eventId" got invalid value ""; Int cannot represent non-integer value: "`

Take this query for example:

```
//gql``
query($orderBy: [AwardsOrderBy!], $limit: Int!, $eventId: Int) {
   allAwards(first: $limit, orderBy: $orderBy, filter: { eventId: { equalTo: $eventId } }) {

//query variables and query
limit = 40
orderBy = "DATE_DESC"
eventId = falsey
useQuery(AWARDS, { variables: { limit, orderBy, eventId } })
```

Now I [would assume](https://github.com/graphile-contrib/postgraphile-plugin-connection-filter/issues/58), that this query would work correctly but the eventId part of the filtering would be completely ignored.

Is there a way round this with graphQL and postgraphile

Here is my current solution without having to have put any thought into it, I just needed it working right now:

```
  const queryVariables = [
    ...(eventId ? [`eventId: { equalTo: $eventId}`] : []),
    ...(awardTypeId ? [`awardTypeId: { equalTo: $awardTypeId}`] : []),
  ]
  const filterVariables = [...(eventId ? [`$eventId: Int`] : []), ...(awardTypeId ? [`$awardTypeId: Int`] : [])]

  const filter = queryVariables.length
    ? `, filter: { ${queryVariables.map((a, index) => {
        return `${a}${queryVariables.length !== index + 1 ? ', ' : ''}`
      })} }`
    : ''

  const query = `
    query($orderBy: [AwardsOrderBy!], $limit: Int!${queryVariables.length ? `, ${filterVariables}` : ''}) {
      allAwards(first: $limit, orderBy: $orderBy${filter}) {
        edges {

///example output:
query($orderBy: [AwardsOrderBy!], $limit: Int!, $awardTypeId: Int) {
  allAwards(first: $limit, orderBy: $orderBy, filter: { awardTypeId: { equalTo: $awardTypeId} }) {
```

Comment: just don't define it? undefined won't be passed - check network request

Comment: Or set it null rather than “falsy”.

Comment: Thanks guys, I get the follow error: `Null literals are forbidden in filter argument input` The problem with not defining them... is I need to set the `filter`.

Comment: pass entire (prepared object) filter as arg ... or not when not required

Comment: Heh updated, though I hadn't read your comment. I believe this is enough to get the grasp of what is going on

Comment: it doesn't matter ... no string literals required at all, this should be avoided ... **you can manipulate `variables` object only** ... then just `allAwards(first: $limit, orderBy: $orderBy, filter: $filter)`

Comment: Ahh this was where I was going wrong then. filter can accept an object itsself. I was doing `filter: { $something: xx}` I can work with that indeed :)